# Show that $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left\{1-\left(k+\frac12\right)\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)\right\}=\frac12\times\log(2\pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I tried to prove that the constant in Stirling's formula is $\sqrt {2\pi}$. Then I used the Euler-Maclaurin formula, so finally this is what I need to prove. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation) gives a hint that we need to use Wallis' product, but I couldn't prove it. Please help.

Comment: @chamsi, Don't do unnecessary edits.

Comment: I assume you proved something like $$
\log n! = \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\log n - n + C + \mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)
$$ where the constant $C$ is given by the sum in question.

Comment: Yes that I did, @Gary.

Comment: Consider https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3258426 With that notation $a_n \to C$ by what you have established so far. The answer explains how to get the value of $C$ via the Wallis product.

Comment: @Gary, that I understood. Thank you. But isn't there a direct way of proving it, in the sense that we start with the series in LHS and then prove RHS?

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668036 ?

Comment: @Martund I'm sorry, I thaught your sum diverges in the first place, but I guess I forgot that for negative numbers, the fractional part was defined as : $$ \left\lbrace x\right\rbrace = x-\left\lceil x\right\rceil $$

Comment: @CHAMSI, I am not using any fractional part function here, the braces are just meant to be higher order brackets.

Comment: Also, the definition of fractional part function is $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ for all real $x$, irrespective of sign.

Comment: @Martund No it isn't. That definition applies for positive real numbers only. Also, your formula holds even if the braces were refering to the fractional part, probably because what's inside the sum is always in $ \left]-1,0\right] $. Anyway, I'm gonna try this.

Comment: @CHAMSI, Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation).

Comment: @Martund Yeah I saw that, it said that was the definition for all $ x\in\left[0,1\right[ $, and I agree with that. Read here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part

Answer (score 0):

Let's define two sequences, $ \left(a_{n}\right)_{n\geq 0} , \left(b_{n}\right)_{n>0}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} $ as follows : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ a_{n}=\frac{n^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-n}\sqrt{n}}{n!}\\ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ b_{n}=\ln{\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right)} $$

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, we have $ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right) $, the following : \begin{aligned} b_{k}&=\ln{\left(\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{e}^{-1}\right)}\\ &=-1+\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)} \end{aligned}

Thus : \begin{aligned} 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(1-\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)}\right)}&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\ln{\left(a_{k+1}\right)}-\ln{\left(a_{k}\right)}\right)}\\ &=1+\ln{\left(a_{n}\right)}-\ln{\left(a_{1}\right)}\\ &=\ln{\left(a_{n}\right)} \end{aligned}

Since : $$ 1-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\underset{\overset{n\to +\infty}{}}{\mathcal{O}}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) $$

Then the series $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 1}{\left(1-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)} $ converges, which means that $ \ln{\left(a_{n}\right)}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\ell_{0}\in\mathbb{R} $, hence, denoting $ \ell=\mathrm{e}^{\ell_{0}} $, we have : $$ n!\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\ell\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{n}{\mathrm{e}}\right)^{n} \ \ \ \ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}1\end{array}$}$$

Now we just need to find what $ \ell $ is, to do so we'll be using the fact that : $$ \frac{}{}\frac{2}{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\left(\frac{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}}{\left(2n\right)!}\right)^{2}=\frac{W_{2n+1}}{W_{2n}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1  \ \ \ \ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}2\end{array}$}$$

Were $ W_{n} $, for $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, stands for Wallis integral : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ W_{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin^{n}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

I'm not gonna detail the second result, simply because it's easy to prove, also it is an exercise that, I think, has been solved many times in this website.

Using our first result, we can write that : $$ \frac{2}{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\left(\frac{2^{2n}\left(n!\right)^{2}}{\left(2n\right)!}\right)^{2}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac{2^{4n}}{n\pi}\times\frac{\ell^{4}n^{4n+2}\mathrm{e}^{-4n}}{\ell^{2}\left(2n\right)^{4n+1}\mathrm{e}^{-4n}}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac{\ell^{2}}{2\pi} $$

Thus $ \ell = \sqrt{2\pi} $, which means $ \ell_{0} $, which is the sum of our series, would then be equal to $ \frac{1}{2}\ln{\left(2\pi\right)} $.

Comment: I am trying to prove Stirling's formula (as I've mentioned in my question as well), so I can't use that to prove it.

Comment: @Martund I've fixed that. The proof is now much more complete I guess.